# The problem of using the ng-repeat command to repeat a photo in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am in the process of implementing my first site with Java programming language and Spring Boot, and I encountered a problem in the front-end section. Due to my lack of previous experience, I don't know what the problem is.
Problem title:
How should I use the ng-repeat command to repeat the image?

Before using the command:

###### Card title

Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.

Go somewhere
    
  
Default command:

```
<br/>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"  >
<img src="../src/images/tube.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
  <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
</div>
```

After using the command:

###### Card title

Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.

Go somewhere
    
  
___________________________________________________________________

[image: The image I intend to repeat]

Comment: can you please mention you have multiple items?

Comment: Following your sample example, ng-repeat work in a same way as for loop works, in example you have added a static data into the loop. Also in you ng-repeat it seems like there is only one data so div is repeated only once. Please try adding json data into items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use **Angularjs** `ng-repeat` you need to assign `items` some data in the form of an array in your controller. You can then reference that with item in the html template and it will repeat the data and you can then reference the specific element in the template.

template:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"  >
  <img src="{{item.img}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{item.description}}</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div
```

controller:

```
class HomeCtrl {
  constructor($scope) {
    'ngInject';
    this.name = 'AngularJS';
    this.items = [
      {
        img: 'http://placekitten.com/200/200',
        title: 'Card title 1',
        description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the cards content.',
      },
      {
        img: 'http://placekitten.com/250/200',
        title: 'Card title 2',
        description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the cards content.',
      },
    ];
  }
}
export default HomeCtrl;
```

I have created [an example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-x5alkx?file=home%2Fhome.controller.js) to show it running.